# Modal box in XSL only working with first element

Tags: xml, xslt, modal-dialog

In my XML-TEI file I have several elements called  which points to another elements,  using @target and @xml:id attributes. I want to click on my  elements and make the  content appear. I've this working, but only in the first . Can you help me solving this?

**XML HEADER**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding ='UTF-8' standalone ='no' ?>
```

**XML**

```
<note xml:id='note1'>Lorem ipsum1</note>
<note xml:id='note2'>Lorem ipsum2</note>
(...)
<term target='#note1'>Name 1</term>
<term target='#note2'>Name 2</term>
```

**XSL HEADER**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs tei"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
```

**XSL**

```
<xsl:template match="tei:term" priority="10">

  <xsl:variable name="target" select="concat(translate(@target, ' ', ''), '#')"/>

  <button class="trigger" id="modalboxxx_{$target}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></button>

  <div class="modal" id="modalboxxx_{$target}">
    <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close-button">x</span>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//tei:note[contains($target, concat('#', @xml:id, '#'))]">
                  <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($target, concat('#', @xml:id, '#')))"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
      const trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
      const closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

      function toggleModal() {
         modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
      }

      function windowOnClick(event) {
         if (event.target === modal) {
             toggleModal();
         }
      }

      trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
      closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
      window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
    </script>

</xsl:template>
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="trigger" id="modalboxxx_#note1#">Name 1</button>
<div class="modal" id="modalboxxx_#note1#"><div class="modal-content">
<span class="close-button">x</span>Lorem ipsum1.</div></div>
```

(just the same for note 2)

Comment: Your <script> is the same for each Model only using .class-selectors. Try to use id-selectors instead.

Comment: thanks! i've tried several things, but i'm just starting with javascript an js (my code was extracted from [sabe.io](https://sabe.io/tutorials/how-to-create-modal-popup-box). Could you help me a little more with the code, please? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (of course I could not test it):

```
  <xsl:template match="tei:term" priority="10">
    
    <xsl:variable name="target" select="concat(translate(@target, ' ', ''), '#')"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="triggerId"    select="concat('trigger_',$target)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="modelId"      select="concat('model_',$target)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="closeId"      select="concat('close_',$target)"/>

    <button class="trigger" id="{$triggerId}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></button>
    <div class="modal" id="{$modelId}">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close-button" id="{$closeId}">x</span>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//tei:note[contains($target, concat('#', @xml:id, '#'))]">
          <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($target, concat('#', @xml:id, '#')))"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
      const modal       = document.querySelector("#<xsl:value-of select="$modelId"/>");
      const trigger     = document.querySelector("#<xsl:value-of select="$triggerId"/>");
      const closeButton = document.querySelector("#<xsl:value-of select="$closeId"/>");
      
      function toggleModal() {
        modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
      }
      
      function windowOnClick(event) {
        if (event.target === modal) {
          toggleModal();
        }
      }
      
      trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
      closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
      window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
    </script>
    
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: thank you so much! however, that didn't work... none of the buttons showed the modal. I've changed each `document.querySelector("#<xsl:value-of select="$modelId"/>");` for `document.getElementById("<xsl:value-of select="$modelId"/>");` and the first term element worked again, but only the first one... Thanks again! Much appreciated.

Comment: Just as a quick note, I solved this question a long time ago and I edited it. However, my changes were deleted and the question marked as unsolved again. Thanks.